# Increase storage for Ubuntu (under Virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox, disk-management

I installed Ubuntu in my VM with fixed storage of 16GB. I added a new disk from Virtual box , also on SATA, but I don't see it in Ubuntu. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: What do you mean by you can't "see" your new disk in Ubuntu?

Comment: I am having same issue, I am using ubuntu 14.04 and Virutalbox 4.3 . I added new SATA Device, but i am not able to mount that drive to virtual box.please help

Answer (score 0):

Run gnome-disks to format the new hardrive:

```
gksu gnome-disks
```

If it's not there, install gparted and run it to format the newly added hardrive as ext3 or ext4:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
gksu gparted
```